# create graph from data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, networking, graph, igraph

I Have data frame representing a grn network.gene in column 1 is connected to gene in column 2 if column3 (link) is set to 1. I run this code but the resulting graph is not correct.

```
  x <- data.frame("g1" = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), "g2" = c(2,3,4,3,4,4), "link" = c(1,0,1,1,0,0))
  g = graph_from_data_frame(x,x$link==1)
 tkplot(g)
```

how can get correct corresponding graph from this data frame?

Answer (score 0):

you must define your dataframe in this way

```
g=data.frame("g1"=c(1,1,2), "g2" = c(2,4,3))

g=graph.data.frame(g)
```